# Problem with recursion for odd number in sequence Java

Tags: java, recursion, sequence

```
public static int calculate(int n){
    if (n <= 1) {
        return 1;
    } else if (n >= 2 && n%2 == 0){
        return (n * calculate(n - 2));
    } else if (n >= 3 && n%2 == 1){
        return n-1 * calculate(n-2);
    } else {
        return n;
    }
```

I need it to make a numerical sequence for odd numbers:

`(n-1) * (n-2) * (n-2)..... * 2`

For example:

`n=9 == 8 * 6 * 4 * 2 or n=11 == 10 * 8 * 6 .....`

And this line `return n-1 * calculate(n-2)` is not working.

Comment: Presumably you mean `(n-1) * calculate(n-2)`. But the compiler will require a return statement for the case where all the if conditions are false.

Comment: ohh sory, I didn't paste all the code. I have a return statement for the case where all if are false. I'm gonna change it in post

Comment: @wdwizzard I voted to reopen, but for the future you should post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to avoid such occurrences.

Comment: Okey, thx a lot and sorry for my mistake :)

Comment: @OP did that change (the parenthesis around the `(n-1)`) fix your issue? If so, this question should be closed (by others) as an issue caused by a typo / not reproducible, since it's something unlikely to help future readers.

Answer (score 0):

You missed on a bracket because of which, the order of operations went wrong and you were getting wrong outputs...

Instead of `return n-1 * calculate(n-2)`, you must write

```
return (n-1) * calculate(n-2)
```

Now you will get the correct output...